# Merge value of 1 array to another array where keys are the same

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 arrays and I want to push a value from one array to another where keys values equal each other.

1st array

```
    $retail_rates=[
    {
        "supplier": "ALAMO",
        "rateTotalAmount": 293.44,
        "estimatedTotalAmount": 495.34, //i want to add this AS retailTotalAmount
        "numDays": 9 // i want to add this
    },
    {
        "supplier": "HERTZ",
        "rateTotalAmount": 317.16,
        "estimatedTotalAmount": 537.43,
        "numDays": 9
    }
]
```

2nd array

```
    $net_rates =[
    {
        "reference_number": "COMPEKYP7537400-2401",
        "supplier": "HERTZ",
        "rateTotalAmount": 203.01,
        "estimatedTotalAmount": 291.21
    },
    {
        "reference_number": "REF_ID:867692955",
        "supplier": "ALAMO",
        "rateTotalAmount": 147,
        "estimatedTotalAmount": 225.58
    }
]
```

What I want to end up with

```
    $final_array=[
    {
        "reference_number": "COMPEKYP7537400-2401",
        "supplier": "HERTZ",
        "rateTotalAmount": 203.01,
        "estimatedTotalAmount": 291.21,
        "retailTotalAmount": 537.43,
         "numDays": 9
    },
    {
        "reference_number": "REF_ID:867692955",
        "supplier": "ALAMO",
        "rateTotalAmount": 147,
        "estimatedTotalAmount": 225.58,
        "retailTotalAmount": 495.34
         "numDays": 9
    }
         // and so on all the way through

]
```

I have tried several loops but can't seem to fill it properly. Please help if you can

Comment: please show us what you tried and what didn't work

Comment: Array values is object or array??

Comment: @Barmar - i tried to add my code that I tried but it was way too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = [];
foreach ($net_rates as $net_key => $net_rate) {
    foreach ($retail_rates as $retail_key => $retail_rate) {

        if ($retail_rate['supplier'] != $net_rate['supplier']) {
            continue;
        }

        $data = $net_rate;
        $data['retailTotalAmount'] = $retail_rate['estimatedTotalAmount'];
        $data['numDays'] = $retail_rate['numDays'];
        $result[] = $data;

        unset($retail_rates[$retail_key]);
        unset($net_rates[$net_key]);
        break;
    }
}
$result = array_merge($result, $retail_rates);
$result = array_merge($result, $net_rates);
dd($result);
```

result is

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "reference_number" => "COMPEKYP7537400-2401"
    "supplier" => "HERTZ"
    "rateTotalAmount" => 203.01
    "estimatedTotalAmount" => 291.21
    "retailTotalAmount" => 537.43
    "numDays" => 9
  ]
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "reference_number" => "REF_ID:867692955"
    "supplier" => "ALAMO"
    "rateTotalAmount" => 147
    "estimatedTotalAmount" => 225.58
    "retailTotalAmount" => 495.34
    "numDays" => 9
  ]
]
```

Comment: Where is `retailTotalAmount` in the result?

Comment: your input does not have `retail_total_amount` keys

Comment: He wrote that `estimatedTotalAmount` in the first array becomes `retailTotalAmount` in the result.

Comment: `"estimatedTotalAmount": 495.34, //i want to add this AS retailTotalAmount`

Comment: this works perfect except sometimes i do not get all suppliers in retail_rates so my net_rates array shrinks. I still want to show all net_rates even if I cant get a retail rate for it.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate one time over the first array and create an assoc array with the supplier as the key. Then iterate over the second array and append it to the first one.

```
$final_array = [];
foreach ($retail_array as $item) {
    $final_array[$item['supplier']] = $item;
}

foreach ($net_array as $item) {
    if (isset($final_array[$item['supplier']])) {
        $final_array[$item['supplier']] = $item + $final_array[$item['supplier']];
    } else {
        $final_array[$item['supplier']] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wrote `"estimatedTotalAmount": 495.34, //i want to add this AS retailTotalAmount` You're not renaming that field.

Comment: sorry this would work but sometimes i do not get all suppliers in retail_rates. I tried and got error 'undefined index 'Dollar'. This is super clean!